# Stitch 4 Images in Rviz

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, image, images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All,

Any ideas on how I would stitch or "sew" 4 kinect images together making ONE panoramic image in rviz?

Thanks,
Andy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54667/stitch-4-images-in-rviz/) by [Andrius](https://answers.ros.org/users/3812/andrius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although more experienced users might answer differently, I don't think what you're asking is possible on `RViz` by itself since it's not an image processing/manipulating tool per se.

`OpenCV` has [a nice stitching capability](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/introduction.html). You should be easily able to transfer the resulting image to ROS by [image_transport](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2